# Send and receive TCP data in ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, telnet

I have a TCP server running which accepts the command "GETHELLO" and return "HELLO".
I test it by using Telnet in linux shell :

```
:~$ telnet 192.168.1.10 3000
Trying 192.168.1.10...
Connected to 192.168.1.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
GETHELLO
HELLO
```

How can I do this in ruby using TCPSocket ? (send "GETHELLO" and read the data "HELLO" returned by the server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```ruby
require 'socket'
sock = TCPSocket.new('192.168.1.10', 3000)
sock.write 'GETHELLO'
puts sock.read(5) # Since the response message has 5 bytes.
sock.close
```

Comment: I edited to make it a bit more Rubyish and not use a hardcoded recv buffer size. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I try this but puts sock.gets no return data and wait indefinitely. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy: does the server send "`HELLO\n`" (with a newline)?  If not then you'll need to determine what constitutes a "response message" (e.g. a fixed-byte length) and change the code accordingly.

Comment: @maerics: isn't it necessary to close that connection? but how?